# Integration by Parts an expected value

Tags: probability, integration

I have the function $q(\theta)=1-\theta$ where $\theta\sim U[0,1]$ and  $f(\theta)$ and $F(\theta)$ are the pdf and cdf.

I have the following integral:

$\int_{0}^{1}( \int_{\theta}^{1} q(x)dx) f(\theta)d\theta$

Using integration by parts:

$u=\int_{\theta}^{1} q(x)dx$

$du=-q(\theta)d\theta$

$dv=f(\theta)d\theta$

$v=F(\theta)$

Replacing in the formula of integration by parts:

$
\int_0^1 \int_{\theta}^{1}q(x)dx \, F(\theta) \, d \theta
 + \int_{0}^{1} q(\theta)F(\theta)d\theta= \int_{0}^{1} q(\theta)F(\theta)d\theta$

Then replacing q and using the fact that F is uniform I get:

$\int_{0}^{1} (1-\theta)\theta d\theta$

But if integrate:

$\int_{0}^{1} \left( \int_{\theta}^{1} q(x)dx \right) f(\theta)d\theta
=
\int_{0}^{1} \left( \int_{\theta}^{1} 1-x \, dx \right) d\theta=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-\theta)^2}{2} d\theta$

And the second I think it is the correct one!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I agree with most of what you've written but think you have concluded that they give different answers when in fact they give the same value if you follow them through.

The required integral:

$$
\int_0^1
\left[
\int_\theta^1 q(x) dx
\right]
f(\theta) d \theta
$$

Using integration by parts:

$$
u = \int_\theta^1 q(x) dx  \quad \Rightarrow
\quad
du = - q(\theta) d \theta
$$

$$
dv = f(\theta) d \theta \quad
\Rightarrow
\quad 
v = \int f(\theta) d \theta  = F(\theta)
$$

The formula for integration by parts:
$$
\int_a^b u dv = \left[ u  v \right]_a^b - \int_a^b v du
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1
\left[
\int_\theta^1 q(x) dx
\right]
f(\theta) d \theta
&=
\left[
\int_\theta^1 q(x) dx \;\;
F(\theta)
\right]_0^1
-
\int_0^1 F(\theta) \, (- q(\theta) ) d \theta
%
\\ &=
\int_0^1 F(\theta) \,  q(\theta)  d \theta
%
\\ &=
\int_0^1 \theta \,  (1 - \theta)  d \theta
%
\\ &=
\int_0^1 \theta - \theta^2  d \theta
%
\\ &=
\left[
 \frac{\theta^2}{2} - \frac{\theta^3}{3}  
\right]_0^1
=
\frac{1}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$

Integrating directly:

$$
\begin{aligned}
%
\int_0^1
\left[
\int_\theta^1 q(x) dx
\right]
f(\theta) d \theta
&=
\int_0^1
\left[
\int_\theta^1 (1-x) dx
\right]
f(\theta) d \theta
%
\\ &=
\int_0^1
\left[
- \frac{(1-x)^2}{2}
\right]_\theta^1
f(\theta) d \theta
%
\\ &=
\int_0^1
\left[
\frac{(1-\theta)^2}{2}
\right]
\, 1 \, d \theta
%
\\ &=
\int_0^1
\frac{(1-\theta)^2}{2}
\times \, 1 \, d \theta
%
\\ &=
\left[
- \frac{(1-\theta)^3}{6}
\right]_0^1
= \frac{1}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$

I.e. we get a value of 1/6 regardless of the method used.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I made a consistent typo when I calculate the value!!

Comment: You're welcome.